# switch button for change theme in android

Tags: java, android, themes

I want change my app theme with a switch Button but I don't know how I should do it? I want that switch change it to a dark theme.

I can't found any things in web.

Comment: Hi!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service. It is recommended to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a folder inside `/app/src/main/res/` directory & name it `values-night`. It will show in Android Studio as values(night) in the project pane. Then for each configuration you need separate files. Such as colors, styles etc. Here colors and style are main.

Here is a sample:

> For normal mode

**colors.xml** (as you wish)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6C63FF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#6C63FF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    
    <color name="mainText">#2D313D</color>
    <color name="textAlt">#8D8F97</color>

    <color name="mainBackground">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

and **styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

> For Night mode

Now in `/app/src/main/res/values-night/` directory do the same as above. Just change the color that matches night mode. For instance:

**colors.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6C63FF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2D313D</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    
    <color name="mainText">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="textAlt">#8D8F97</color>

    <color name="mainBackground">#2D313D</color>
</resources>
```

and **styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

To switch from one mode to another, add these line in activity:

```java
switch_btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    if(isNightModeOn){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        switch_btn.text = "Enable Dark Mode"
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        switch_btn.text = "Disable Dark Mode"
    }
})
```

Comment: excuse me, I can not find the folder you mentioned at the beginning in my project!    
    app/src/main

Comment: This is the folder where you've created your project. To find it easily, In Android Studio's left pane (where the project folder hierarchy is shown), right click on `app` directory then select `Open in` then select your file manager.

Answer (score 2):

I created a library that you can create your custom themes and change them dynamically with ripple animation.

check it here: https://github.com/imandolatkia/Android-Animated-Theme-Manager

also in this repository, there is a sample app that you can see what should you do.

[image]

Comment: thank for your suggestion. How can I do it in java ? I can't write kotlin

Comment: @SinaMoradi, I updated repo readme with java sample codes. check it here: https://github.com/imandolatkia/Android-Animated-Theme-Manager/blob/main/README.md

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. this is very nice!  but it does not work for me, I get a lot of error. Anyway Thank you Mr. Dolatkia

Comment: feel free to ask any question about it, I can help you in implementation also.